# Queried TEXT incomplete in Textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

I am making a form that edits a user's post on a website i am making. An issue that i currently have is that the page queries the content of the user's post and inserts it into a `textarea` just as the user wrote it BUT the first chunk of the post is gone and only shows the rest of what the user wrote. Example if the user wrote 2 paragraphs, posts it then goes to the website and see's his post, it shows up just fine. However when the user goes into his Control Panel and edits his post, the page queries the post by title, queries the content of the post but only the second paragraph is inserted into the `textarea`.

I tried increasing the number of rows of the `textarea` thinking it was running out of rows but it didnt change a thing. Then i set the max length of the `textarea` but that as well had no effect. I even `echo`'d what was being queried out of the `textarea` into the `article` tags and it all appeared just fine!

This is my form, and its posted how `php` is `echo`'ing it:

```
echo "<form action=\"update_sermon.php\" method=\"post\" id=\"postform\">";
echo "<sert>SERMON TITLE: <input type=\"text\" id=\"sermon_name\" name=\"sermon_name\" value=\"$title\"></input></sert><br>";
echo "<cont>CONTENT:<br><textarea cols=\"85\" rows=\"25\" maxlength=\"60000\" name=\"sermon_content\" value=\"$content\"></textarea></cont><br>";
echo "<publish><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" id=\"submit\"></input></publish>";
echo "</form>";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off-topic but you could make your code much more readable by using a combination of single and double quotes.

Comment: `<textarea>` does NOT have a `value`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- now i know.

Comment: @xR34P3Rx Glad to hear it, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the content between delimiters:

```
<textarea>**CONTENT HERE**</textarea>
```

like so:

```
echo "<textarea cols=\"85\" rows=\"25\" maxlength=\"60000\" name=\"sermon_content\">$content</textarea>";
```

Instead of using the `value` atribute

Comment: I cant believe i didnt think of this. I put the content between the `<textarea></textarea>` instead of adding it as an attribute. Ill chose this as answer when it lets me. Thanks!